# How to use createElement to create a new table?

Tags: javascript, dom

Why the following code doesn't work?

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function addTable() {
        var table = document.createElement('table');
        table.innerHTML = "<tr><td>123</td><td>456</td></tr>";
        document.getElementById("addtable").appendChild(table);
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="submit" value="New Table" onClick="addTable()"/>
    <div id="addtable"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, setting the innerHTML property of a `table` element or table section element (like `tbody` or `thead`) does not work on Internet Explorer (EDIT: I just checked - with [ietester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage) and plain IE8. Result is "unknown runtime error" for IE6 and IE8, and it crashes IE7 but that might be an IEtester specific problem).

The [DOM  standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/ecma-script-language-binding.html) way of adding rows to a table is using the `insertRow()` method on a table or table section element (look for HTMLTableElement and HTMLTableSectionElement in that DOM spec) :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function addTable() {
    var c, r, t;
    t = document.createElement('table');
    r = t.insertRow(0); 
    c = r.insertCell(0);
    c.innerHTML = 123;
    c = r.insertCell(1);
    c.innerHTML = 456;
    document.getElementById("addtable").appendChild(t);
}
</script>
```

In the script, there is no explicit table section being created. AFAIK, a TBODY is automatically created, and rows are inserted in there.

EDIT: regarding IE, I should point out that you can add a table with content and all by setting the `innerHTML` property, but the html you inject in there must be a complete table. So this does work, even on IE:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function addTable() {
    var html = "<table><tr><td>123</td><td>456</td></tr></table>";
    document.getElementById("addtable").innerHTML = html;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, Indeed, it throws runtime error! We should go by this method, or traditional create/append cycles for all tbody, tr and td.

Comment: +1 Correct on all accounts. `innerHTML` is read-only for `table` and `tbody` in IE.

Comment: my bad...typo. Change `table` to `t`. Fixed in the answer

Comment: Hi, i can't put sth like that inside?
c.innerHTML = "<label for="name">Name:</label>";

Comment: yeeen: put what inside what? AFAIK, you can set the innerHTML property of a table cell to whatever you like as long as it is valid HTML.

Comment: @Roland: i hv checked ur answer as the soln

Answer (score 0):

```
//_table my current table
var table = document.createElement('table'); //new table
table.innerHTML = _table.innerHTML; //clone table innerHTML
```